# Index not working

Tags: indexing, auxiliary-files

I'm working on a document. There's an index there, but for some reason when I change things in it it doesn't update the rendered outcome and I can't correct it.

I tried erasing the `.ind` file, but then it just render the document without an index at all (instead of re-creating the index as I would have expected).

What am I doing wrong?

Specifics:

there's a defs file that has:

```
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
```

the grand `.tex` file has:

```
\input{defs}
.
.
.
\printindex
```

But: when I change, for example `\index{Installing}` to `\index{installing}` 
the index keeps having "Installing" and not "installing".

When I erase the `.ind` file and re-render it (even after ten times of trying) the document simply does not include an index at all and stops before it.

There is no new `.ind` file being generated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384) No need to add thanks to your posts, simply upvote any answers you may receive. After you delete the `.ind` you need to run LaTeX multiple times for the index to be generated. After doing that does the problem persist?

Comment: yes. I've tried to render it now about ten times, just to make sure. I've even tried restarting the whole program. Still no index - Uri

Comment: Minimal example please, did you remember to run the actual indexing program?

Comment: There really is nothing grand to describe: there's a "definitions" file that includes '\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex' and the original file (that inputs the "definitions") includes '\printindex' ... that's it. maybe it has to do with the fact that this whole project was copied to my computer recently? (I doubt it of course, but I learned not to underestimate these things' voodoo)

Comment: Still, please update your question with as small an example that you can make that still show this problem. That will make it much much easier for us to help. Even though there are a lot of Wizards around here, their crystal ball are usually quite cloudy...

Comment: Besides, creating the MWE is a valuable exercise, as it often leads the user to figure out the problem themselves.

Comment: The above is not a MWE, it has to be something that we can copy'n'page to our favourite editor and test

Comment: @user25291 Look at `.ilg` file. There's a chance that you have defined indexes in pages that have non-numerical page number. Look at this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131092

Answer (score 27):

Just to avoid confusion, the way to produce a generic index should be

1. include `\usepackage{makeidx}`
2. Put a `\makeindex` command in the preamble
3. Put a `\printindex` where the index should appear
4. Run LaTeX which generates an `"fname".idx` file
5. Run makeindex `"fname".idx` to generate the `"fname".ind`
6. Run LaTeX again to include the `.ind` file and generate the index in the document

From your question, it is not clear if all of these parts are included in your process.

Comment: Yes. I apologize if I am unclear, but yes, I follow these steps - it seems as if if the .ind file exists it does not change it, and if it does not exist it does not generate it.

Comment: @user25291 You have to run MakeIndex (step 5 above) every time you change the indexed terms. If instead of `makeidx` you load the package `imakeidx`, then `pdflatex` will do it for you, provided you have a fairly recent TeX distribution.

Comment: I had to use the package `imakeidx` in my case. Great tip.

Answer (score 10):

In my case, replacing makeidx with imakeidx makes it work. Probably something missing in my installation - didn't debug.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
text\index{test}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on that?

Answer (score 3):

No really an answer, but here is a working MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
text\index{test}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

and it works just fine on my system. Does it work on yours?

Comment: @Student this is not a forum, please post a question on the site