# makeindex: Illegal Roman number

Tags: page-numbering, indexing, appendices

I'm currently writing some appendices and I'm wondering why *some* keywords don't show up in the index.

The page-number is redefined for every section of the Appendix (A..., B..., C..., etc.).

I've discovered, that there is always this error:

> Scanning input file testfile.idx...done (0 entries accepted, 4 rejected).

Content of file `testfile.idx`:

```
\indexentry{A}{C1}
\indexentry{B}{C1}
\indexentry{C}{C2}
\indexentry{D}{C2}
```

Content of makeindex-logfile:

```
Scanning input testfile.idx...
!! Input index error (file = testfile.idx, line = 1):
   -- Illegal Roman number: position 2 in C1.
!! Input index error (file = testfile.idx, line = 2):
   -- Illegal Roman number: position 2 in C1.
!! Input index error (file = testfile.idx, line = 3):
   -- Illegal Roman number: position 2 in C2.
!! Input index error (file = testfile.idx, line = 4):
   -- Illegal Roman number: position 2 in C2.
done (0 entries accepted, 4 rejected).
```

This works fine for pages starting with A, B and E (probably more), but fails with C and D. Therefore, I'm afraid that makeindex is interpreting C and D as Roman numerals for 100 and 500, respectively.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{arabic}\renewcommand{\thepage}{C\arabic{page}}
    A\index{A}  B\index{B}
    \clearpage
    C\index{C}  D\index{D}
    \cleardoublepage
    \printindex
\end{document}
```

**What do I have to do to get makeindex interpreting "C1", etc. as it is?**

---

UPDATE:

Problem on the pagenumbering encountered with hyperref:

[image: Adobe Reader]

Comment: I'm afraid this is an inherent limitation of MakeIndex.

Comment: Hmm, still wondering why "C4" is not working, but "C-4" does. It seems that makeindex can indeed accept a non-roman character but refuses to work with arabic numbers. I'm confused...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are not totally committed to that page format makeindex is happier if you have a `-` separator:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{arabic}\renewcommand{\thepage}{A-\arabic{page}}
    A\index{A}  B\index{B}
    \clearpage
    C\index{C}  D\index{D}
    \cleardoublepage


    \pagenumbering{arabic}\renewcommand{\thepage}{C-\arabic{page}}
    A\index{A}  B\index{B}
    \clearpage
    C\index{C}  D\index{D}
    \cleardoublepage
    \printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]

As egreg noted in comments (and included here with permission:-) the trick to having an invisible page separator is the `page_compositor_  setting in a makeindex style.

```
\protected\def\?{}
\renewcommand\thepage{C\?\arabic{page}
```

in the LaTeX file and

```
page_compositor "\\?"
```

in a `foo.ist` file to be called by

```
 makeindex -s foo filename
```

or a `filename.mst`

Comment: Yes, I've had this before, but to be honest - I don't like it very much (see also on page A-15), as I think page A15 is smoother. Also I don't know why the minus solves this issue. I'll think about this and maybe I'll customize the source code of my very own version of `makeindex` if nothing else is possible...

Comment: @DL6ER I'm sure in a previous life I had a makeindex style that made a separator visible to makeindex but typestting as empty, failed to recreate it just now, but it may come back to me:-)

Comment: @DL6ER oh I used same page format as you suggest in source2e :-)

Comment: `\protected\def\?{}`, `\renewcommand\thepage{C\?\arabic{page}` in the LaTeX file and `page_compositor "\\?" in a `foo.ist` file to be called by `makeindex -s foo filename` or a `filename.mst` file

Comment: This is working indeed. You should convert your comment into an answer, as this is probably the best solution one can apply without modifying some sources.

Comment: @DL6ER egreg told me to edit it in to here :-)

Comment: @DL6ER The idea for a `page_compositor` expanding to nothing was David's.

Comment: I've encountered a problem with this solution: Despite tons of errors hyperref produces, the pagenumber gets kind of crappy (refer to the picture I have added to the question). How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

A cheap work-around if you really don't want C-1, C-2, … :

Go ahead and do it with C- anyway. LaTeX will generate `foo.idx` from your `foo.tex` file and then MakeIndex will create `foo.ind` will no rejections. When you're happy with everything else and still have those hated C- page numbers in your index, open `foo.ind` and do a global search-and-replace to change every C- to just C. Fix your `foo.tex` file to use C not C- in the appendix and LaTeX it one last time and there you have it.

Comment: You'll want a script or batch file or makefile so you don't have to remember or type these steps.

Answer (score 1):

Addition for `hyperref` to David Carlisle's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131116/16967):

```
\usepackage{hyperref}

% disable \? in page labels, destinations and links
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\?\relax}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\theindex{\let\?\@empty}
\makeatother
```

A full example using `\jobname.mst` as style file for makeindex.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.mst}
page_compositor "\\?"
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\?}{}
\protected\def\?{}

%%% hyperref support
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\?\relax}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\theindex{\let\?\@empty}
\makeatother
%%%

\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{arabic}\renewcommand{\thepage}{C\?\arabic{page}}
    A\index{A}  B\index{B}
    \clearpage
    C\index{C}  D\index{D}
    \cleardoublepage
    \printindex
\end{document}
```