# "Four-Sided" Documents: Make New Chapters Start Only on Page Numbers That Are 4n+1

Tags: page-breaking, double-sided

There is the option `twoside`, to make chapters start on odd pages only. This way, when the document is printed two-sided, a new chapter will always start on the right side (odd page).

My question is: Is it possible to define a four-sided document? My reason is that, when I want to print two document pages on one side of the paper sheet, and also double-sided; so there are four different pages on one sheet of paper.

The document is divided into several chapters, and when I update one chapter, I would like to be able to just exchange that chapter's pages in the folder in which I keep the printed chapters (disregarding page numbers). This requires that every chapter starts only at page 5, 9, 13, ..., i.e. 4n+1.

I am using the `scrbook` documentclass. The following code starts a chapter at page 3, using the `twoside` option. I would like it to start at page 5.

```
\documentclass[12pt,abstracton,titlepage,parskip=false, no, no, twoside=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\chapter{first chapter} \blindtext

\chapter{second chapter}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: What are the options `abstraction` and `no` (used twice) good for?

Comment: You could also learn how to use tools like `pdftk` (or `pdfjam` which wraps the LaTeX package `pdfpages`) and do this as post-processing (after the PDF file is generated), instead of trying to do everything from inside LaTeX.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR but that wouldn't be any fun.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I assume that would also not change the page numbering.

Comment: @Teepeemm Yes correct; I imagine that's what is actually wanted too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following does what you want by patching the `\scr@startchapter` macro which is internally used by `\chapter` to not use `\cleardoublepage` but to use `\clearfourpage`, which does what you want.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,abstracton,titlepage,parskip=false, no, no,
twoside=true,open=right]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


\makeatletter
\patchcmd\scr@startchapter
  {\cleardoublepage}{\clearfourpage}{}{\GenericError{}{Patching failed}{}{}}
\newcommand*\newpage@twocolumn@helper
  {%
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \hbox{}%
    \newpage
    \if@twocolumn
      \hbox{}%
      \newpage
    \fi
  }
\newcommand*\clearfourpage
  {%
    \clearpage
    \if@twoside
      \ifodd\c@page
      \else
        \newpage@twocolumn@helper
      \fi
      \ifodd\numexpr\c@page/2\relax
      \else
        \newpage@twocolumn@helper
        \newpage@twocolumn@helper
      \fi
    \fi
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{first chapter}
%\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext
\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext

\chapter{second chapter}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** The following also resets the page counter to 1 for each chapter and sets the `\thepage` macro to include the `\thechapter` counter:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,abstracton,titlepage,parskip=false, no, no,
twoside=true,open=right]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


\makeatletter
\patchcmd\scr@startchapter
  {\cleardoublepage}{\clearfourpage\setcounter{page}{1}}{}{\GenericError{}{Patching failed}{}{}}
\newcommand*\newpage@twocolumn@helper
  {%
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \hbox{}%
    \newpage
    \if@twocolumn
      \hbox{}%
      \newpage
    \fi
  }
\newcommand*\clearfourpage
  {%
    \clearpage
    \if@twoside
      \ifodd\c@page
      \else
        \newpage@twocolumn@helper
      \fi
      \ifodd\numexpr\c@page/2\relax
      \else
        \newpage@twocolumn@helper
        \newpage@twocolumn@helper
      \fi
    \fi
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\tableofcontents
\clearfourpage
\renewcommand*\thepage{\thechapter--\arabic{page}}%
\setcounter{page}{1}
\chapter{first chapter}
\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext
%\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext

\chapter{second chapter}
\blindtext
\section{first section}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\section{second section}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

(note that in this MWE the pages in the ToC are correct)

Comment: Why is necessary to test for `\if@twocolumn` in `\newpage@twocolumn@helper`? When in two column mode, does `newpage` change to another column only?

Comment: The MWE works. Thank you! in my own document, however, it works with all chapters except one that starts at page 67 (previous chapter goes to page 66), which I still need to figure out.

Also, can this code be made to count actual page numbers in the document, thus not being fooled by the pagecounter resetting after the table of contents, list of figures, and list of tables?

Comment: @JohnKormylo the standard `\cleardoublepage` of LaTeX uses `\hbox{}\newpage` on following pages, that's why I do the same. Note that the real page-breaking code part of `\clearpage` is a `\newpage` as well (together with more code to do a few other things...).

Comment: @Marie.P. you should only change the page numbering on pages which are right pages in the first place. All of LaTeX's internals decide on even/odd pages and the correct layout based on the page counter. So what you should do after the ToC etc. is `\clearfourpage\pagenumbering{arabic}` in the first place, that doesn't lie within the scope of this macro (in normal twoside documents you'd do `\cleardoublepage\pagenumbering{arabic}`).

Comment: @Marie.P. also in this case it might be a good idea to reset the page counter on every chapter and have a prefix for the chapters, so use something like `\clearfourpage\setcounter{page}{1}\renewcommand*\thepage{\thechapter---\arabic{page}}` before every chapter (or add this to the chapter code...). This way your ToCs would stay correct for your chapters even if you only replace one chapter.

Comment: when I use your MWE, with the following number of blindtexts in chapter 1: `\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext` , so as only to fill 2 pages (such that chapter 1 ends on page 2), then the second chapter starts on page 3 instead of 5. 

In general, your code works when the previous chapter ends on page 4n, 4n+1, and 4n+3, but not 4n+2; because it then continues on page 4n+3 instead of 4n+5.

Comment: @Marie.P. stupid error. Now corrected in new version of the answer. I'll also remove the edit.

Comment: `\clearfourpage\setcounter{page}{1}\renewcommand*\thepage{\thechapter---\arabic{page}}` - when trying to implement this, as in `\newcommand\mychapter[1]{\setcounter{page}{1}
\chapter{#1}}` and `\renewcommand*\thepage{\thechapter---\arabic{page}}` , everything works as intended in the document, but the table of contents does only display the naked page numbers, without the `\thechapter---`  beforehand.  How can this be reflected in the table of contents?

Comment: @Marie.P. can you please ask a follow up question? You can link back to this question there. Please provide a new MWE there which contains the `\renewcommand*\thepage{...}` code. Also there is a better way to get the page counter reset at every chapter, you could use `\makeatletter\@addtoreset{page}{chapter}\makeatother` instead (untested, might cause pages to start at 0 for each chapter).

Comment: @Marie.P. ok, that `\@addtoreset` solution will break the start on every (4n+1)-th page. Instead We could add that reset to the `\scr@startchapter` macro after the `\clearfourpage`. See my new edit on how I'd do all this.

Comment: Is there a way to change the geometry of a page depending on whether it is `4n+1`, `4n+2`, `4n+3`, or `4n+4`?

Comment: The command `\renewcommand*\thepage{\thechapter---\arabic{page}}` prevents the index from being printed, without throwing any error.

I used this MWE from daleif's answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98204/index-not-working

Comment: @Marie.P. please ask a follow up question referencing this answer of mine and including a new MWE, which uses `\renewcommand*\thepage{....}` and states that you want to include an index.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524477/change-page-geometry-for-a-four-sided-not-two-sided-document?noredirect=1#comment1326719_524477

Here is the new question.

Comment: @Marie.P. that question doesn't include an index. In fact I'm not even sure what you're asking in that question...