# Change page geometry for a four-sided (not two-sided) document

Tags: geometry

I want to have different page geometry for pages 4n+1 and 4n+2, and 4n+3 and 4n+4. I want this is because I print two pages per page, with front and back side, i.e. 4 pages per sheet. When filing the printed documents, I want the text to be further away from the filing edge, to improve readability.

In [this question on four-sided documents,](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522813/four-sided-documents-make-new-chapters-start-only-on-page-numbers-that-are-4n) I have obtained help with making sure that a new chapter always starts on a page 4n+1.

The MWE is this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,abstracton,titlepage,parskip=false, no, no,
twoside=true,open=right]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=1.5in, bottom=0.5in, left=1in, right=1in} %for pages 4n+1, 4n+2
\geometry{top=0.5in, bottom=1.5in, left=1in, right=1in} %for pages 4n+3, 4n+4


\makeatletter
\patchcmd\scr@startchapter
  {\cleardoublepage}{\clearfourpage}{}{\GenericError{}{Patching failed}{}{}}
\newcommand*\newpage@twocolumn@helper
  {%
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \hbox{}%
    \newpage
    \if@twocolumn
      \hbox{}%
      \newpage
    \fi
  }
\newcommand*\clearfourpage
  {%
    \clearpage
    \if@twoside
      \ifodd\c@page
      \else
        \newpage@twocolumn@helper
      \fi
      \ifodd\numexpr\c@page/2\relax
      \else
        \newpage@twocolumn@helper
        \newpage@twocolumn@helper
      \fi
    \fi
  }
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\newcommand\mychapter[1]{\clearfourpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\chapter{#1}}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{first chapter} \blindtext
\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext

\chapter{second chapter}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

with currently two `geometry` specifications (of which currently only the latter is currently used for all pages).

I want the first one,

`\geometry{top=1.5in, bottom=0.5in, left=1in, right=1in}`,

to be applied to page numbers 4n+1 and 4n+2, and

`\geometry{top=0.5in, bottom=1.5in, left=1in, right=1in}`

to be applied to page numbers 4n+3 and 4n+4.

---

### Edit: Clarification

I want to print, punch-hole, and file the document like this:
[image]

The bottom of the two pages in the upper part of the photo, as well as the top of the pages in the bottom, is close to the folds. Since the document has several pages and the fold around the middle gets thick, this impairs readability a little. So I want to move the top pages up and the bottom pages down. This should include header and footer.

**In the picture, I want to move the part of the page that the document uses away from the red areas and into the empty blue areas, as indicated by the orange arrows.**

Given that any chapter starts on page `4n+1`, as per the previously solved question, the two bottom pages are `4n+1`and `4n+2`, and the two top pages are `4n+3` and `4n+4`.

I imagine one reason why two-sided documents have different left and right, i.e. inner and outer, margins is also readability: you don't want text to disappear in the binding of the book.
I have just the same problem, but since I print two pages per sheet, my document is four-sided, not two-sided, and the different pages need to move up or down, instead of left and right.

Comment: Interesting problem. I found a solution, but (its in german and) it is not soley implemented in latex, but uses some other tools as well https://stefankonarski.de/content/a5-buchdruck-mit-latex

Comment: @Sango please note that the suggestions in that link use some outdated packages (for example `german`).