# Redefining Page Numbers Makes Index Disappear

Tags: indexing, makeindex

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\renewcommand*\thepage{\thechapter---\arabic{page}}

text\index{test}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

This file has only two pages, and no index. When I comment out the line `\renewcommand*\thepage{\thechapter---\arabic{page}}`, the index is generated on the third page.

I followed the troubleshooting in, and took the MWE from, [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98204/index-not-working); and I took the modified page numbers from [this one.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522813/four-sided-documents-make-new-chapters-start-only-on-page-numbers-that-are-4n?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default “page compositor” is a hyphen.

You can change it to `---` by using a personal style. The simplest way is to generate an `.ist` file in the working directory.

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{emdash.ist}
page_compositor "---"
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex[options=-s emdash]

\renewcommand*\thepage{\thechapter---\arabic{page}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title}

text\index{test}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

Source: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/support/makeindex/ind.pdf

Available on your TeX Live system as `texdoc ind`.

Of course it's up to you to change the page number format before printing the index.